# Polynomial matrices, division and remainder

Tags: matrices, polynomials

I work in control and the following problem stumbled at me: Given to matrices N and D, obtain matrices Q and R to hold N = Q*D + R.

This solution allows to find compensator/observer pole allocation matrices.

I thank for the help.

Comment: $Q=0$ and $R=N$ does the trick.  Presumably you want to impose some additional restrictions to make it less trivial.

Comment: Sure it holds. But assume N and D are such that $N D^{−1}$ is improper for some entries